# 'text' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS7... How to get text value from alert.textFields[0]?

Tags: ios, text, swift, alert

My code was like this before updating to Xcode6-beta3:

```
cell.text = rowData["list_name"] as String
```

I have updated this to:

```
cell.textLabel.text = rowData["list_name"] as String
```

but this part of the code:

```
let alertText = alert.textFields[0].text
```

I can't understand how to get text from textFields[0] without using .text

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT:

Now with the GM version of Xcode I get this error instead.
[image]

Would be super happy for a response, getting tired of changing this now :P

Also, how would you be able to decrypt that kind of error message? Could be good to know.

Thanks

Comment: `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 8. Use its replacement instead.

Comment: I'm not using UIAlertView, I'm using UIAlertController.

Comment: Then how are you getting a deprecation warning for something that didn't exist in iOS 7?

Comment: Well I don't think the problem is with the alert. It's with "text" since "text" is unavailable. I need to get the textFields value and before I did with .text in the end. But now I can't use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `alert.textFields` has the type `[AnyObject]` (corresponding
to the Objective-C `id`), so that the compiler does not know that
`alert.textFields[0]` is a `UITextField` which has a `text` method.

This should work:

```
let alertText = (alert.textFields[0] as UITextField).text
```

Comment: This got rid of the error, but I can't try just yet. Have a problem with NSUserDefaults. Will mark as answered if proved to be the solution, thanks!

Comment: Have now solved my other problem and your solution seems to work! Many thanks!

Comment: "so that the compiler does not know that alert.textFields[0] is a UITextField which has a text method." But you can try to call any `@objc` method on `AnyObject`. Does it work differently for properties?